# ¿Cómo obtener los nombres de las variables de los valores pasados a una función?

Tags: python, lista, variables, variables-globales

En el código de abajo tengo una función que he creado a modo de ejemplo que recibe los argumentos necesarios para componer una lista de comprensión (output, bucles, condiciones) y los devuelve en forma de lista comprimida.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi función se le llama así:

```
function(Output: str #"i, j"#, *Conditions: tuple[str,] #"i==j", "j==k"#, **Collections: dict_items([(str: list),]) #i=lista, j=lista#)
```

Quiero que a la hora de devolver la lista comprimida, el valor de las listas pasadas en los bucles (values de los **kwargs en las función) sean reemplazados por la variable de dicha lista. De forma visual sería lo siguiente:

```
    Output obtenido: [i for i in [0, 1, 2, 3, 4] for j in [0, 2, 1, 3, 4] if i==j]
    Output objetivo: [i for i in lista1 for j in lista2 if i==j]
```

Para esto, he visto un código que consigue hacerlo, pero lo aplica en una función muy simple:

```
def hola(saludo):
    for nombre, valor in list(locals().items()):
        if valor == saludo:
            print(f"El nombre de la variable es '{nombre}'")

saludo_text = 'Hola mundo!'
imitacion_text='Hola mundo!'
hola(saludo_text)
```

¿Cómo podría hacer para introducir eso en la siguiente función?

```
def list_comprehension(output, *conditions, **loops):
    '''Function to make list comprehensions easier and faster. Returns a list type object
    with the next extructure:
            [output loops conditions]
        Where:
    \toutput: list's values that will be returned
    \tconditions: [... if condition]
    \tloops: [... for loops.key in loop.value ...]'''

    output=re.split('[\s?,?]+', output)
    l=output if len(output)==1 else ['('+', '.join(output)+')']
    for key, value in loops.items():
        globals()[key]=value
        l.append(f'for {key} in {value}')
    for condition in conditions:
        l.append(f'if {condition}')
    else:
        return '['+' '.join(l)+']'


lista1=[0,1,2,3,4]
lista2=[0,2,1,3,4]
lista=list_comprehension('i', 'i==j', i=lista1, j=lista2)
```

Comment: Creo que no es posible saber fácilmente el nombre de la variable. Y si 2 variables tuvieran el mismo valor, no podrías saber cuál de las 2 es la recibida.

Comment: De modo rastrero se podría hacer un with open, leer el propio archivo, localizar los lugares en los que se le llama a la función y verificar si el valor de la variable coincide. Pero sería demasiado rastrero

Comment: [Encontré algo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2749857/13419694). Igual me pregunto para qué quisieras los nombres en lugar de sus valores.

Comment: Está en la pregunta: //    Output obtenido: [i for i in [0, 1, 2, 3, 4] for j in [0, 2, 1, 3, 4] if i==j]//
    Output objetivo: [i for i in lista1 for j in lista2 if i==j]

Comment: Ah, claro. La idea es generar la expresión en lugar de obtener su resultado. Otra opción sería pasar un string y listo. Yo en lugar de concatenar `for`s usaría `zip`. Por ejemplo `[i for i, j in zip(lista1, lista2) if i==j]`. Creo que es más legible y más eficiente.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Revisando el código

Aunque dices que es rastrera, esta solución es la que más daría en el blanco. La idea consiste en

- tomar el código fuente y obtener su arbol de sintaxis abstracta (ast), que representa la estructura del código
- Buscar el primer nodo en la linea `stacks[2].frame.lineno`, que no da el número de linea donde la función con la que queremos trabajar fue llamada, que sea un `ast.Call`, es decir, una llamada a un llamable.
- Recorrer los argumentos de palabra clave y, asumiendo que el argumento es una variable, obtener su nombre como string. Con una modificación, se puede, por ejemplo, enviar error si el argumento no es una variable.

---

```
import inspect
import ast

def find_keywords_origin():
    stacks = inspect.stack()
    frame = stacks[2].frame

    node = next(node for node in ast.walk(ast.parse(inspect.getsource(stacks[-1].frame)))
                if getattr(node, "lineno", None) == frame.f_lineno and isinstance(node, ast.Call))

    return dict((keyword.arg, keyword.value.id) for keyword in node.keywords)
    
var1 = var2 = "a"

def caller(a, b):
    print(find_keywords_origin())

caller(a=var1,b=var2)
```

---

#### En "tiempo de ejecución" (usando inspect)

No es exactamente posible lograr lo que buscas de otra forma, ya un valor puede ser referenciado por varias variables al mismo tiempo y no parece haber una forma obvia (y dudo que la haya) de saber que variable recibe la función en "tiempo de ejecución".

Podemos partir de obtener todas las variables que existen que referencian a ese valor:

```
def find_all_vars(obj):
    # Aqui guardamos los nombres de variables (sin repetir) que se nos crucen con ese valor
    variables = set()

    # inspect.stack nos permite acceder, entre otras cosas, a todos los ambitos de variables existentes en el momento.
    # El 2 descarta los primeros dos ambitos (esta funcion y la función que llamó a ésta)
    for info in inspect.stack()[2:]:
        # Recorremos el diccionario de variables locales del ambito actual
        for name, value in info.frame.f_locals.items():
            # Usamos is para saber si value y obj apuntan al mismo objeto en memoria.
            # Si usaramos ==, podrían ser dos valores diferentes pero que son iguales (ejemplo, [] == [] es True, [] is [] es False)
            if value is obj:
                variables.add(name)

    return variables

strvar = "hola mundo"
a = 1

def func():
    var1 = var2 = strvar
    print(find_all_vars(var1))

func()
```

Produce (en orden arbitrario):

```
{'strvar', 'var1', 'var2'}
```

A partir del código proporcionado, se pueden hacer modificaciones para poner restricciones y así elegir una de las variables, como por ejemplo:

- Dar error si el valor es referenciado más de una vez
- Tomar la primera variable encontrada, asi nomás.
- Buscar en un ambito especifico, como el global, y no en todos los ambitos. Aunque esto aun podría darte alguna variable extra.